# Cannot contain a Container resulting in a RenderOverflow Error

Tags: flutter, nested, widget

Basically I have a Screen where I want a gap between the bottom of a 'Tile' and the actual bottom of the screen and within this tile there is a slab of text (Multi Line String) that is too big for the screen so I am trying to make it scrollable.

I cannot seem to make any layer of the nested Containers be Contained by a MediaQuery, SizedBoxed, FittedBox, Expanded Wisget, Flex Widget or anything else I try.

This means the String and it's container causes that RenderOverflow.

I speculate the problem is widgets are stacking on top of each other and I am missing some knowledge on how they all add their height values together but yeah what would I know.

This is my current code but I have tried many different things with different widgets.

```
class ReadNewsArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<NewsArticle> newsArticles;
  final int actualIndex;
  ReadNewsArticle({Key? key, required this.newsArticles, required this.actualIndex}) : super(key: key);

  TextStyle articleTitleText = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
                end: Alignment.topLeft,
                colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.deepOrangeAccent], stops: [0.1,1])),
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:45.0, left: 15),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));
                      },
                      child: Text('<Back'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 12),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 12, left: 0),
                                child: Text(
                                  newsArticles[actualIndex].articleTitle,
                                  style: articleTitleText,
                                  softWrap: true,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            ClipOval(
                              child: Image(
                                image: newsArticles[actualIndex].profilePic,
                                width: 40,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 3),
                              child: Text(
                                newsArticles[actualIndex].name,
                                // style: profileTileNameText,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Text(
                                    newsArticles[actualIndex].actualArticle,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    maxLines: null,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: remove the `height` from the container in the body.   its overflow, because you define parent height , then defined again in the children widget. too much unnecessary widget

Comment: I have deleted that and the renderoverflow error still gets thrown when I go to run it, and the Multi-String text get's cut off.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tweak a bit your code but it is super messy, here is a version with an added SingleChildScroll view to remove the vertical overflow. Plus I removed the height in the last expanded row so it adapts to the size of the text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewsArticle {
  String articleTitle;
  String name;
  String actualArticle;
  ImageProvider profilePic;
  NewsArticle({
    required this.articleTitle,
    required this.name,
    required this.actualArticle,
    required this.profilePic,
  });
}

class ReadNewsArticle extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<NewsArticle> newsArticles;
  final int actualIndex;
  ReadNewsArticle(
      {Key? key, required this.newsArticles, required this.actualIndex})
      : super(key: key);

  TextStyle articleTitleText = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 35,
    color: Colors.black,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.bottomRight,
              end: Alignment.topLeft,
              colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.deepOrangeAccent],
              stops: [0.1, 1])),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0, left: 15),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text('<Back'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 30,
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, top: 12),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                    top: 8.0, bottom: 12, left: 0),
                                child: Text(
                                  newsArticles[actualIndex].articleTitle,
                                  style: articleTitleText,
                                  softWrap: true,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            ClipOval(
                              child: Image(
                                image: newsArticles[actualIndex].profilePic,
                                width: 40,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 3),
                              child: Text(
                                newsArticles[actualIndex].name,
                                // style: profileTileNameText,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: SizedBox(
                                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                  child: Text(
                                    newsArticles[actualIndex].actualArticle,
                                    softWrap: true,
                                    maxLines: null,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ]),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```